# How to check compare value of string variable in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I am trying out building a NodeJS express app with using express-handlebars as my Template engine. In my render function, I am passing a  JSON object to be used to compose some content conditionally as below:

JSON OBJECT:

server.js

```
let MyObject = {
    'email':'dev@example.com',
    'acc_type':'Employer'
}
```

RENDER FUNCTION:

```
router.get('dashboard-settings',(req, res)=>{
     res.render('dasboard-settings',{'title':'Settings','mydata':MyObject })
})
```

Originally, I did:

dashboard-settings.handlebars

```
{{#if mydata.acc_type == 'Employer'}}
<div class='display-text'>Welcome Employer</div>
{{else}}
<div>Welcome Freelancer</div>
{{/if}}
```

But this did not work. After further research, I read somewhere where it was suggested I use the handlebars.js library and create something called a helper which I did like this:

process.js

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function (a, b, options) {
    if (a == b) { return options.fn(this); }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

And then I changed the way I did in dashboard-settings.handlebars like this

```
{{#ifeq mydata.acc_type 'Employer'}}
<div class='display-text'>Welcome Employer</div>
{{else}}
<div>Welcome Freelancer</div>
{{/ifeq}}
```

Now this is firing a error, and regardless of why that is, I know there is also a possibility that I am not properly accessing the `mydata.acc_type` value

How can I fix this completely. Below is the error I am getting in my browser:

```
Error: Missing helper: "ifeq"
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\helpers\helper-missing.js:19:13)
    at Object.wrapper (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\internal\wrapHelper.js:15:19)
    at Object.eval [as main] (eval at createFunctionContext (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\javascript-compiler.js:262:23), <anonymous>:11:102)
    at main (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:208:32)
    at ret (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\runtime.js:212:12)
    at ret (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\compiler.js:519:21)
    at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:250:9)
    at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (B:\MyProjects\Node Projects\cs\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.js:173:15)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error thrown?

Comment: I have added the error log

Answer (score 0):

In your case you actually don't need a new helper, you can use the existing `eq` helper:

```
{{#if (eq mydata.acc_type 'Employer')}}
<div class='display-text'>Welcome Employer</div>
{{else}}
<div>Welcome Freelancer</div>
{{/if}}
```

---

But if you still want a custom helper you have to register it this way:

```js
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')

var app = express()

var hbs = exphbs.create({extname: '.handlebars'})
app.engine(hbs.extname, hbs.engine)
app.set('view engine', hbs.extname)

Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function (a, b, options) { ... })
```

Comment: Alright, but is accessing the value with ```mydata.acc_type``` the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are messing the `()` in your first code

```
{{#if (mydata.acc_type == 'Employer')}}
<div class='display-text'>Welcome Employer</div>
{{else}}
<div>Welcome Freelancer</div>
{{/if}}
```

If you want to use the helper
in your `app.js`

```
handlebarshelper=require(your/path/to/process.js)
app.engine('hbs', handlebars({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    helpers: handlebarsHelper
}));
```

Comment: Okay so right now I think its better to use the already existing eq helper. I have modified my code to using the eq helper like ```{{#if (eq mydata.acc_type 'Employer')}}``` and then display what needs to be displayed. But its still firing an error ```Error: Missing helper: "eq"```

Comment: it says missing helper because it is still in your code if you want to use the first approach you have to delete the helper, otherwise if you want to use the helper you have to implement it properly, I have updated my answer regarding the helper